# InputField with lookup relationship not working within a table

Tags: visualforce, lookup, apexinputfield

My issue is after putting a lookup input field into a table, although it displays properly and by clicking the lookup button it can successfully open the lookup dialog, it can't select - When I click on one result in the lookup dialog, it doesn't pick it up.

My code generally looks like this:

```
<table class="wTableInfo1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
    <tbody>
        <apex:form >
            <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Order__c.FieldSets.Request_Mandatory}" var="f"> 
                <tr>
                    <td>{!f.label} <span class="required">*</span></td>
                    <td><apex:inputField id="OrderDetailsField" value="{!parentOrder[f.fieldPath]}"/></td>
                </tr>                                                 
            </apex:repeat>   
        </apex:form>    
    </tbody>                            
</table>
```

I have tested by moving the apex:form section out of the table and removing all the `<td>`, `<tr>` tags and it works fine for me. But if I put them in a table, the lookup field stopped working. It seems that it turns into readonly after putting in a table. This issue can also be replaced without using fieldset.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
<apex:form>
<table/>
</apex:form>
```

submit action should be within apex:form